# Show that $\underline{\int}_a^b(-f(x)) \, dx=-\overline{\int}_a^bf(x) \, dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

If f be bounded function on $[a,b]$, prove that
$$\underline{\int}_a^b(-f(x)) \, dx=-\overline{\int}_a^bf(x) \, dx$$

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\underline{\int}$, is it the supremum of lower sums?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing, except I thought it meant "negative a" and so on.

Comment: $\underline{\int}_a^b$ represents lower integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any subinterval $I_j = [x_{j-1},x_j]$ of a partition $P$ we have $\inf_{x \in I_j}[-f(x)] = -\sup_{x \in I_j}[f(x)]$

Forming  lower and upper sums we have

$$L(P,-f) = \sum_{j=1}^n\inf_{x \in I_j}[-f(x)](x_j - x_{j-1}) = -\sum_{j=1}^n\sup_{x \in I_j}[f(x)](x_j - x_{j-1}) =  - U(P,f) \\ \implies \underline{\int}_a^b (-f(x)) \, dx = \sup_P L(P,-f) = \sup_P [-U(P,f)] = - \inf_P U(P,f) = -\overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \, dx  $$